# KDE Template Header not displaying

Tags: graphics, compiling, templates

The KDE template won't display the .png image file.  I haven't changed anything from the stock settings.  I wanted to give the template a whirl, but all I see is a label called oxygen-header for a space where the image file should be.  What do you guys think is the issue?

Comment: It would be helpful to know which template you mean. I tried the one from http://www.kde.org/kdeslides/ and the Makefile works fine for me.

Comment: I tried the oxygen template.  Does the Makefile have anything to do with it?  I use WinEdt and just textify-->ps-->pdf.  From the initial textify, nothing pops up for the image.

Answer (score 2):

You have to build directly to pdf. Since it is a png file you have to compile it with `pdflatex`. Standard `latex` can't embed png files. A simple `pdflatex example-talk` works fine for me.

You can build it using the Makefile if your editor supports it. But someone else might be able to tell you how to do this with texify or WinEdt.